# Tests of within subjects contrasts in R

Tags: r, anova

I have run a split splot model in SPSS (via repeated measures function) and I would like to reproduce my results using R. To do so I used ezANOVA function from ez package to obtain sphericity tests and correction and type III SS. I have read that aov function does not give type III SS. So far the results are identical with those from SPSS but I cannot tell so when I run tests of within subjects contrasts. I use polynomial contrasts and my factor has six levels. What I manage to get is t-values instead of f-values or f-values but not the same as in SPSS. Here is my data and code

```
id    subj  treat  m1    m2    m3    m4    m5   m6
1       1     1   455   460   510   504   436   466
2       2     1   467   565   610   596   542   587
3       3     1   445   530   580   597   582   619
4       4     1   485   542   594   583   611   612
5       5     1   480   500   550   528   562   576
6       6     2   514   560   565   524   552   597
7       7     2   440   480   536   484   567   569
8       8     2   495   570   569   585   576   677
9       9     2   520   590   610   637   671   702
10     10     2   503   555   591   605   649   675
11     11     3   496   560   622   622   632   670
12     12     3   498   540   589   557   568   609
13     13     3   478   510   568   555   576   605
14     14     3   545   565   580   601   633   649
15     15     3   472   498   540   524   532   583
```

m1-m6 represent measurements in 6 different time points. My code for the contrasts.

```
long.df<- melt(data, id=c('subj','treat'))
long.df<- long.df[order(long.df$subj)]
names(long.df)<- c('subj','treat','time','meas')
mod<- lm(meas~time + time^2 + time^3 + time^4 + time^5, long.df)
summary(mod) # this is how I obtain t-values for the polynomial contrasts #
mod1<- aov(meas~time + time^2 + time^3 + time^4 + time^5, long.df)
summary(mod1, split=list(time=list("Linear"=1, "Quad"=2,'q'=3,'f'=4,'fif'=5))) 
# this is how i obtain f-values #
```

I think that the F-values correspond to type 1 SS (as I use aov function). How am I wrong? Is there a way to conduct the Tests of within subjects contrasts and obtain type III SS so I will have identical results to SPSS? Here are the SPSS results. Many thanks in advance!

```
Source     time    Type III SS/   df/    Mean Square/        F/   Sig.  
time     Linear     123662.881/    1/     123662.881/   83.591/   .000  
      Quadratic       5928.007/    1/       5928.007/   18.968/   .001  
          Cubic      10462.676/    1/      10462.676/   28.075/   .000  
        Order 4        798.193/    1/        798.193/    4.010/   .068  
        Order 5       1702.743/    1/       1702.743/    4.878/   .047
```

Comment: Since my comment got removed during migration here it is again: I can't answer this because I don't understand why F-stats should be used. I would do `long.df$time <- ordered(long.df$time); summary(lm(meas~time, data=long.df))`, which gives you t-stats. Since there is only one dependent in the model, using `anova` on that model you have only one F-value for time. Thus, imo the question of type I/II/III is irrelevant here.

Comment: @ Roland. I would like to use F-stats so I can obtain identical results to SPSS which uses F-stats to test contrasts within subjects in repeated measures anova. Additionally the results from t-stats I obtained using R appear to have different statistical significance than those from SPSS, so I am trying to figure out how am I wrong in R.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you did with SPSS (you don't seem to consider repeated measures in R), but the SPSS output doesn't look correct to me if you are trying to use polynomial contrasts.

Comment: @ Roland. In SPSS when you run a univariate repeated measures anova, there is  an option with which you can perform tests of within subjects contrasts. These tests use F-ratios and type III SS and show the trend of the effect. At this case I chose polynomial contrasts. In R I used Anova function from car package and ezANOVA function to run the repeated measures model but I can't find sth similar to SPSS to analyze the contrasts. The two solutions I mentioned above gave different results, so I am wondering how am I wrong and how I could run the same tests using polynomial contrasts as SPSS.

Comment: Sorry, my understanding of SPSS is not sufficient to help you. However, I would try to get the actual time values of these measurements instead of using an ordered factor and polynomial contrasts.